# select the two columns contained > 1 row have the same value

Tags: php, sql, row, conditional-statements

I have a table like this:

```html
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.2.11
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: May 11, 2016 at 05:38 AM
-- Server version: 5.6.21
-- PHP Version: 5.6.3

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `jadwal`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `data_kuliah`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data_kuliah` (
`id_datkul` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_matkul` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_kelas` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_dosen` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_dosen2` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `data_kuliah`
--

INSERT INTO `data_kuliah` (`id_datkul`, `id_matkul`, `id_kelas`, `id_dosen`, `id_dosen2`) VALUES
(0, 2, 1, 14, 6),
(1, 3, 1, 14, 6),
(2, 4, 1, 12, 0),
(3, 1, 1, 16, 0),
(4, 9, 1, 6, 14),
(5, 7, 1, 8, 0),
(6, 6, 1, 8, 15),
(7, 22, 1, 12, 14),
(8, 23, 1, 7, 13),
(9, 24, 1, 10, 14),
(10, 26, 2, 8, 0),
(11, 27, 1, 8, 0),
(12, 28, 1, 10, 14),
(13, 28, 2, 14, 10),
(14, 29, 1, 10, 14),
(15, 29, 2, 14, 10),
(16, 30, 1, 15, 7),
(17, 31, 1, 15, 0),
(18, 33, 1, 16, 0),
(19, 69, 1, 15, 7),
(20, 69, 2, 7, 15),
(21, 70, 1, 15, 7),
(22, 70, 2, 7, 15),
(23, 45, 1, 7, 15),
(24, 46, 1, 7, 15),
(25, 47, 1, 14, 10),
(26, 48, 1, 14, 10),
(27, 49, 1, 9, 0),
(28, 49, 2, 9, 0),
(29, 50, 1, 14, 6),
(30, 62, 1, 8, 15),
(31, 65, 1, 15, 7),
(32, 68, 1, 15, 7),
(33, 26, 3, 8, 0);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `data_waktu`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data_waktu` (
`id_waktu` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `kd_hari` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `kd_jam` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_ruang` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=99 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `data_waktu`
--

INSERT INTO `data_waktu` (`id_waktu`, `kd_hari`, `kd_jam`, `id_ruang`) VALUES
(0, 1, 1, 1),
(1, 1, 2, 2),
(2, 1, 3, 3),
(3, 1, 4, 4),
(4, 1, 5, 6),
(5, 1, 6, 7),
(6, 1, 7, 1),
(7, 1, 8, 0),
(8, 1, 9, 0),
(9, 1, 10, 0),
(10, 1, 11, 0),
(11, 1, 12, 0),
(12, 1, 13, 0),
(13, 1, 14, 0),
(14, 1, 15, 0),
(15, 1, 16, 0),
(16, 1, 17, 0),
(17, 2, 1, 0),
(18, 2, 2, 0),
(19, 2, 3, 0),
(20, 2, 4, 0),
(21, 2, 5, 0),
(22, 2, 6, 0),
(23, 2, 7, 0),
(35, 2, 10, 0),
(36, 2, 11, 0),
(37, 2, 12, 0),
(38, 2, 13, 0),
(39, 2, 14, 0),
(40, 2, 15, 0),
(41, 2, 16, 0),
(42, 2, 17, 0),
(43, 3, 1, 0),
(44, 3, 2, 0),
(45, 3, 3, 0),
(46, 3, 4, 0),
(47, 3, 5, 0),
(48, 3, 6, 0),
(49, 3, 7, 0),
(51, 3, 9, 0),
(52, 3, 10, 0),
(53, 3, 11, 0),
(54, 3, 12, 0),
(56, 3, 13, 0),
(57, 3, 14, 0),
(58, 3, 15, 0),
(59, 3, 16, 0),
(60, 3, 17, 0),
(61, 4, 1, 0),
(62, 4, 2, 0),
(63, 4, 3, 0),
(64, 4, 4, 0),
(65, 4, 5, 0),
(66, 4, 6, 0),
(67, 4, 7, 0),
(68, 4, 8, 0),
(69, 4, 9, 0),
(70, 4, 10, 0),
(71, 4, 11, 0),
(72, 4, 12, 0),
(73, 4, 13, 0),
(74, 4, 14, 0),
(75, 4, 15, 0),
(76, 4, 16, 0),
(77, 4, 17, 0),
(78, 5, 1, 0),
(79, 5, 2, 0),
(80, 5, 3, 0),
(81, 5, 4, 0),
(82, 5, 5, 0),
(83, 5, 6, 0),
(84, 5, 7, 0),
(85, 5, 8, 0),
(86, 5, 9, 0),
(87, 5, 10, 0),
(88, 5, 11, 0),
(90, 5, 13, 0),
(91, 5, 14, 0),
(92, 5, 15, 0),
(93, 5, 16, 0),
(94, 5, 17, 0),
(95, 2, 8, 0),
(96, 2, 9, 0),
(97, 3, 8, 0),
(98, 5, 16, 0);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `dosen`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dosen` (
`id_dosen` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `kd_dosen` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `nip_dosen` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nm_dosen` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `keterangan` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `dosen`
--

INSERT INTO `dosen` (`id_dosen`, `kd_dosen`, `nip_dosen`, `nm_dosen`, `keterangan`) VALUES
(6, 'D 03', '197401071999032001', 'Endang Sugiharti S.Si.,M.Kom.', ''),
(7, 'D 04', '197405172006041001', 'AlamsyahS.Si.,M.Kom.', ''),
(8, 'D 05', '197404202008121001', 'Much Aziz Muslim S.Kom., M.Kom.', ''),
(9, 'D 06', '197810252003122001', 'Florentina Yuni Arini, S.Kom., M.Kom.', ''),
(10, 'D 07', '198005252005011001', 'Riza Arifudin, S.Pd., M.Cs.', ''),
(12, 'D 09', '197001021999031002', 'Isa Akhlis S.Si., M.Si.', ''),
(13, 'D 10', '198707062014041003', 'Anggy Trisnawan Putra, S.Si.,M.Si.', ''),
(14, 'D 11', '198509102014071116', 'Aji Purwinarko, S.Si., M.Cs', ''),
(15, 'D 12', '198805012014041001', 'Budi Prasetiyo, S.Si., M.Kom.', ''),
(16, 'D 13', '-', 'Fajar Arif Setyawan, S.Pd., M.Pd.', '');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `hari`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hari` (
`kd_hari` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hari` varchar(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `hari`
--

INSERT INTO `hari` (`kd_hari`, `hari`) VALUES
(1, 'senin'),
(2, 'selasa'),
(3, 'rabu'),
(4, 'kamis'),
(5, 'jumat');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `jam`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jam` (
`kd_jam` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `jam_kuliah` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `jam`
--

INSERT INTO `jam` (`kd_jam`, `jam_kuliah`) VALUES
(1, '07:00:00'),
(3, '08:40:00'),
(4, '09:30:00'),
(5, '10:00:00'),
(6, '11:00:00'),
(7, '12:00:00'),
(8, '12:30:00'),
(9, '12:40:00'),
(10, '13:00:00'),
(12, '15:00:00'),
(15, '15:30:00'),
(16, '16:00:00');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `kelas`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `kelas` (
`id_kelas` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nm_kelas` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `keterangan` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `kelas`
--

INSERT INTO `kelas` (`id_kelas`, `nm_kelas`, `keterangan`) VALUES
(1, 'K - 1', ''),
(2, 'K - 2', ''),
(3, 'K - 3', '');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `mata_kuliah`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mata_kuliah` (
`id_matkul` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `kd_matkul` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `nm_matkul` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `sks` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `semester` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=71 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `mata_kuliah`
--

INSERT INTO `mata_kuliah` (`id_matkul`, `kd_matkul`, `nm_matkul`, `sks`, `semester`) VALUES
(1, 'M 01', 'Kalkulus', 3, 'Ganjil [1]'),
(2, 'M 02', 'Algoritma dan Pemrograman', 2, 'Ganjil [1]'),
(3, 'M 03', 'Praktik Algoritma dan Pemrograman', 1, 'Ganjil [1]'),
(4, 'M 04', 'Fisika', 3, 'Ganjil [1]'),
(6, 'M 06', 'Sistem Operasi', 2, 'Ganjil [1]'),
(7, 'M 07', 'Praktik Sistem Operasi', 1, 'Ganjil [1]'),
(9, 'M 08', 'Pengantar Teknologi Informatika', 2, 'Ganjil [1]'),
(22, 'M 21', 'Interaksi Manusia dan Komputer', 3, 'Ganjil [3]'),
(23, 'M 22', 'Teori Bahasa dan Otomata', 3, 'Ganjil [3]'),
(24, 'M 23', 'Teknik Kompilasi', 3, 'Ganjil [3]'),
(26, 'M 25', 'Jaringan Komputer', 2, 'Ganjil [3]'),
(27, 'M 26', 'Praktik Jaringan Komputer', 1, 'Ganjil [3]'),
(28, 'M 27', 'Sistem Basis Data', 2, 'Ganjil [3]'),
(29, 'M 28', 'Praktik Sistem Basis Data', 1, 'Ganjil [3]'),
(30, 'M 29', 'Analisis Algoritma', 3, 'Ganjil [3]'),
(31, 'M 30', 'Etika Profesi', 2, 'Ganjil [3]'),
(33, 'M 32', 'Teori Graph', 3, 'Ganjil [5]'),
(45, 'M 44', 'Kecerdasan Buatan', 3, 'Ganjil [5]'),
(46, 'M 45', 'Praktik Kecerdasan Buatan', 1, 'Ganjil [5]'),
(47, 'M 46', 'Grafika Komputer', 3, 'Ganjil [5]'),
(48, 'M 47', 'Praktik Grafika Komputer', 1, 'Ganjil [5]'),
(49, 'M 48', 'Komputer dan Masyarakat', 3, 'Ganjil [5]'),
(50, 'M 49', 'Sistem Pendukung Keputusan', 3, 'Ganjil [5]'),
(62, 'M 61', 'Keamanan Jaringan', 3, 'Ganjil [7]'),
(65, 'M 64', 'Jaringan Syaraf Tiruan', 3, 'Ganjil [7]'),
(68, 'M 67', 'Logika Fuzzy', 3, 'Ganjil [7]'),
(69, 'M 33', 'Teknik Multimedia', 3, 'Ganjil [5]'),
(70, 'M 34', 'Praktik Teknik Multimedia', 1, 'Ganjil [5]');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `ruang`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ruang` (
`id_ruang` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `kd_ruang` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nm_ruang` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kapasitas` int(6) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `ruang`
--

INSERT INTO `ruang` (`id_ruang`, `kd_ruang`, `nm_ruang`, `kapasitas`) VALUES
(1, 'R 01', 'LAB 1', 0),
(2, 'R 02', 'D9 LAB. KOMP. II', 0),
(3, 'R 03', 'D2-314', 0),
(4, 'R 04', 'D2-310', 0),
(5, 'R 05', 'LAB ILKOM 1 D1-301 ', 0),
(6, 'R 06', 'LAB 2', 0);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `data_kuliah`
--
ALTER TABLE `data_kuliah`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_datkul`);

--
-- Indexes for table `data_waktu`
--
ALTER TABLE `data_waktu`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_waktu`);

--
-- Indexes for table `dosen`
--
ALTER TABLE `dosen`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_dosen`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `dsn_nama_key` (`nm_dosen`);

--
-- Indexes for table `hari`
--
ALTER TABLE `hari`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`kd_hari`);

--
-- Indexes for table `jam`
--
ALTER TABLE `jam`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`kd_jam`);

--
-- Indexes for table `kelas`
--
ALTER TABLE `kelas`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_kelas`);

--
-- Indexes for table `mata_kuliah`
--
ALTER TABLE `mata_kuliah`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_matkul`);

--
-- Indexes for table `ruang`
--
ALTER TABLE `ruang`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_ruang`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `data_kuliah`
--
ALTER TABLE `data_kuliah`
MODIFY `id_datkul` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=34;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `data_waktu`
--
ALTER TABLE `data_waktu`
MODIFY `id_waktu` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=99;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `dosen`
--
ALTER TABLE `dosen`
MODIFY `id_dosen` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=17;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `hari`
--
ALTER TABLE `hari`
MODIFY `kd_hari` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `jam`
--
ALTER TABLE `jam`
MODIFY `kd_jam` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=17;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `kelas`
--
ALTER TABLE `kelas`
MODIFY `id_kelas` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `mata_kuliah`
--
ALTER TABLE `mata_kuliah`
MODIFY `id_matkul` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=71;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `ruang`
--
ALTER TABLE `ruang`
MODIFY `id_ruang` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=7;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

My SQL

```html
select (select hari.hari from data_waktu join hari on data_waktu.kd_hari=hari.kd_hari order by rand() limit 1) as 'HARI', (select jam.jam_kuliah from data_waktu join jam on data_waktu.kd_jam=jam.kd_jam order by rand() limit 1) as 'jam_kuliah', (select nm_ruang from ruang order by rand() limit 1) as 'nm_ruang', id_datkul from data_kuliah
```

Example output like this:
[Example output like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IQaH.jpg)

My question is, how to display the records only if the two columns contained more than one row have the same value?

I am very confused about this, please help

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query...

```
SELECT *
FROM data_kuliah
WHERE id_dosen IN (
    SELECT id_dosen
    FROM data_kuliah
    GROUP BY id_dosen
    HAVING COUNT(id_datkul) > 1
    )
and
id_dosen2 IN (
    SELECT id_dosen2
    FROM data_kuliah
    GROUP BY id_dosen2
    HAVING COUNT(id_datkul) > 1
    )
```